# Granting permission using camera package pauses the debugger on an exception

Tags: flutter, dart, camera, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

I am using the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package for a simple functionality. I am mostly following the [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart) the package provided. When I open the camera widget page, the package automatically prompts to provide permission to the camera and microphone. After clicking allow to both the permissions the debugger is paused with an exception:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (A CameraController was used after being disposed.
Once you have called dispose() on a CameraController, it can no longer be used.).
```

Here is the required code :

```
class CameraPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CameraPageState createState() => _CameraPageState();
}

class _CameraPageState extends State<CameraPage>
    with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  CameraController _controller;
  List<CameraDescription> _availableCameras;
  ...

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    _initialize();
  }

  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    await _getCameras();
    _controller = CameraController(_availableCameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
    await _controller.initialize();
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
      _controller?.dispose();
    } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (_controller != null) {
        _setCurrentCamera(_controller.description);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  Future<List<CameraDescription>> _getCameras() async {
    List<CameraDescription> camDescriptions;
      camDescriptions = await availableCameras();

      _availableCameras = camDescriptions;
    return camDescriptions;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }


  Future<void> _setCurrentCamera(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
    if (_controller != null) {
      await _controller.dispose();
    }
    _controller = CameraController(
      cameraDescription,
      ResolutionPreset.high,
      enableAudio: false,
    );

    // If the _controller is updated then update the UI.
    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (mounted) setState(() {});

      if (_controller.value.hasError) {
        print('Camera error ${_controller.value.errorDescription}');
      }
    });

    try {
      await _controller.initialize();
    } on CameraException catch (e) {
      _showCameraException(e);
    }

    if (mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _switchCamera() {
    if (_controller != null && !_controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
      CameraLensDirection direction = _controller.description.lensDirection;
      CameraLensDirection required = direction == CameraLensDirection.front
          ? CameraLensDirection.back
          : CameraLensDirection.front;
      for (CameraDescription cameraDescription in _availableCameras) {
        if (cameraDescription.lensDirection == required) {
          _setCurrentCamera(cameraDescription);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }


  void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
    String errorText = 'Error: ${e.code}\nError Message: ${e.description}';
    print(errorText);
  }

}
```

The debugger is pointing the exception here:

```
  Future<void> _initialize() async {
    await _getCameras();
    _controller = CameraController(_availableCameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
    //-------------HERE------------------
    await _controller.initialize();
    if (!mounted) {
      return;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Once I resume the debugger and try opening this camera page again there is no error/exception anymore. It Is happening only after accepting permissions for the first time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

May be the actual culprit is `didChangeAppLifecycleState`.

Once you call `await _controller.initialize();` and the permission dialog is shown, the lifecycle event `AppLifecycleState.inactive` is triggered and current controller is disposed as per your code in `didChangeAppLifecycleState`, hence when the application resumes after permissions given and tries to continue, it throws error.

Try removing

```
if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
  _controller?.dispose();
}
```

Or have a local variable to check if initializing and ignore dispose when initiliazing like

```
Future<void> _initialize() async {
  await _getCameras();
  _controller = CameraController(_availableCameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
  _initializing = true;
  await _controller.initialize();
  _initializing = false;
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

and in `didChangeAppLifecycleState`

```
if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive && !_initializing) {
  _controller?.dispose();
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

May be, I think I found the issue, the actual issue is `didChangeAppLifecycleState` as expected, the `if` clause in the `didChangeAppLifecycleState`, if it truns out to be true, `_controller` is being disposed, if not `_setCurrentCamera` is just disposing any active controller. Hence when you invoke initialize and wait for permissions, before permission future resolves, the `_controller` is being disposed by `didChangeAppLifecycleState`.

My solution would work with simple change. Change your `initState` to

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _initializing = true; // set to true
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  _initialize();
}
```

change your `_initialize` function to make `_initializing = false` after intializing like,

```
Future<void> _initialize() async {
  await _getCameras();
  _controller = CameraController(_availableCameras[0],ResolutionPreset.high);
  await _controller.initialize();
  _initializing = false; // set to false
  if (!mounted) {
    return;
  }
  setState(() {});
}
```

and your `didChangeAppLifecycleState` to

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
  if(_initializing){
    return;
  }
  if (state == AppLifecycleState.inactive) {
    _controller?.dispose();
  } else if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
    if (_controller != null) {
      _setCurrentCamera(_controller.description);
    }
  }
}
```

This way, if `_initializing == true` you never dispose the current controller.

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've tried it. But it is the same issue again.

Comment: can't we make use of the `controller.value.isIntialized` to perform these checks?

Comment: I think you can, I just forgot that the `CameraController` had a status field :D

Comment: Just try ```if((!controller?.value?.isIntialized)??false){
    return;
  }```

Comment: can you share the snippet how you check?

Comment: I am having this. exception when I test the app on a device. But with emulator, it throws no exception.

Comment: Even that doesn't work? I tried it on emulator before I posted.

Comment: Yeah that is what I said. It works on the emulator but not on a real device

Comment: Same error on the real device too? May be I'll give it a try on mine.

Comment: yeah the same exception. I used a. moto g5plus